# Maven release plugin scmReleaseCommitComment parameter

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

I am using maven release plugin for automated releases from Jenkins without any Jenkins-plugins. Release commit, tag and development commit are created in Git and released project is deployed to Nexus.

What I try to achieve is to change the release commit message. As of [release plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html) there is an option `scmReleaseCommitComment`, which is per default `@{prefix} prepare release @{releaseLabel}`. Maven command look like following and all variables are non empty values.

```
mvn -f ${projectpath}pom.xml release:clean release:prepare release:perform -DreleaseVersion=${RELEASE_VERSION} -DdevelopmentVersion=${DEVELOPMENT_VERSION}-SNAPSHOT -Dtag=v${RELEASE_VERSION} -DscmReleaseCommitComment=${RELEASE_COMMENT}
```

Adding `scmReleaseCommitComment` does no effect and commits are still done with default message. What am I missing here?

Comment: You are sure you are using version `3.0.0-M1` of the release plugin?

Comment: Great thanks a lot! I just got blind i guess :)

Answer (score 1):

That feature was introduced in version 3.0.0-M1 of the maven-release-plugin. You can set it to the latest version in the `<plugins>` section of your pom.xml, as in the example bellow:

```
<plugins>
  [...]
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
  </plugin>
  [...]
</plugins>
```

Not that you can set the `scmReleaseCommitComment` in the command line as you showed in your question, using  `mvn ... release:perform ...-DscmReleaseCommitComment=${MY_RELEASE_COMMENT}`, or you can set it in pom.xml:

```
<plugins>
  [...]
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
    <configuration>
      <scmReleaseCommitComment>@{prefix} my comment @{releaseLabel}</scmReleaseCommitComment>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  [...]
</plugins>
```